# jQuery UI Dialog Conflicts

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, modal-dialog

I have run into an issue when getting the jQuery UI dialog to popup over a tab view which in turn contains three floated panels (divs). The code goes something like this

```
<body>
<div id='dialog'>My Dialog</div>
<div id='mytabs'>
<ul><li><a href='#tabA'>Tab A</a></li><li><a href='#tabB'>Tab B</a></li></ul>
<div id='tabA'>
<div id='toolpanel' style='float:left;width:40px'>Content</div>
<div id='proppanel' style='float:left;width:200px'>Content</div>
<div id='datapanel' style='float:left;clear:right;width:100px'>Content</div>
</div>
<div id='tabB'>...</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Originally, I was expanding the third panel to fill the whole of the available client area.  Something along the line of

```
var wh = $('#tabA').width() - $('#toolpanel').outerWidth() - $('#proppanel').outerWidth();
$('#datapanel').css('width',wh + 'px');
$('#dialog').dialog({modal:true});
```

However, with this setup I found that the third panel, datapanel floated down below its siblings as soon as I opened the dialog.  I have temporarily put in a little hack that is preventing this

```
$('#datapanel').css('width',wh - 28 + 'px');
```

Essentially, preventing the datapanel from taking up the full space left over after placing its siblings.

I don't get it.  I thought the jQuery UI dialog does into an absolutely positioned layer with a default zIndex of 1000.  If that is the case why should attempting to show it cause my datapanel to float down?  And why should that bit of arithmetic, wh - 28, stop that from happening?

I'd much appreciate any help with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of your resizing, not because of jQuery UI, I'll try to explain exactly why the best I can.

You have to keep in mind that `tabA`, as an element without a prescribed width, will, by default, take up 100% of its container (and not the sum of widths of its children, which is what you seem to have assumed), and for this reason your arithmetic when trying to resize `datapanel` doesn't work. Actually, if you comment out the dialog invoking line, you'll see that `tabB` breaks and falls under the fold because of the resizing.

You can fix this either by defining a style for tabA's width or use this piece of code

```
var whA = $('#toolpanel').outerWidth(true) + $('#proppanel').outerWidth(true) + $('#datapanel').outerWidth(true);

$('#tabA').css('width',whA + 'px');
```

You also seem to have neglected the fact that all elements are made of margins+border+padding+content.

So, when you say

```
var wh = $('#tabA').width() - $('#toolpanel').outerWidth() - $('#proppanel').outerWidth();
```

first of all, by using just outerWidth() instead of outerWidth(true) you are ignoring the margins on the two inner divs.

Then in:

```
 $('#datapanel').css('width',wh + 'px');
```

you are setting the width [which just relates to content] of datapanel to `wh`, but according to what you have calculated in wh, what you should be setting is the entire width of the div [including the margin, border and padding].

So, by subtracting

```
$('#datapanel').outerWidth(true)-$('#datapanel').width()  //margins+border+padding of datapanel
```

in `wh` you get the desired width.

In conclusion, here's a code snippet that should work for you:

```
var whA = $('#toolpanel').outerWidth(true) + $('#proppanel').outerWidth(true) + $('#datapanel').outerWidth(true);

$('#tabA').css('width',whA + 'px');

var wh = $('#tabA').width() - $('#toolpanel').outerWidth(true) - $('#proppanel').outerWidth(true)-$('#datapanel').outerWidth(true)+$('#datapanel').width();


$('#datapanel').css('width',wh + 'px');
$('#dialog').dialog({modal:true});
```

Comment: Not sure why I did not accept this answer when I read it.  Must have slipped my mind :-/